# Meet doesn't work on your browser, how to fix it?

Tags: browser

I'm using firefox 74.0 and while I want to using Google Meet with Firefox (https://meet.google.com/) it is not supported. "Meet doesn't work on your browser." Anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming related question, and therefore is off-topic here. In the future, please use [su] for this sort of question. For more information about this site, see the [help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling your browser? Some unnecessary extensions can cause issues and may need to be disabled. You can also try clearing out the browser’s cache by going to //settings/clearBrowserData.
Some extension like User Agent Switcher will not allow this.

I'm using the same version of firefox and it works for me.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have tried to refresh my firefox, and it works..
Thank you for your help.